# Data perturbation - How to perform it?

Tags: r, statistics, simulation

I am doing some projects related to statistics simulation using R based on "Introduction to Scientific Programming and Simulation Using R" and in the Students projects session (chapter 24) i am doing the "The pipe spiders of Brunswick" problem, but i am stuck on one part of an evolutionary algorithm, where you need to perform some data perturbation according to the sentence bellow:

"With probability 0.5 each element of the vector is perturbed, independently
of the others, by an amount normally distributed with mean 0 and standard
deviation 0.1"

What does being "perturbed" really mean here? I dont really know which operation I should be doing with my vector to make this perturbation happen and im not finding any answers to this problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess it is just adding a Normal(0,0.1) random variable to each element.  In R, you need the `rnorm` function to generate these random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perturbing just means adding a small, noisy shift to a number. Your code might look something like this.

```
x = sample(10, 10)
ind = rbinom(length(x), 1, 0.5) == 1
x[ind] = x[ind] + rnorm(sum(ind), 0, 0.1)
```

`rbinom` gets the elements to be modified with probability `0.5` and `rnorm` adds the perturbation.

Answer (score 1):

```
# using the most important features, we create a ML model: 

m1 <- lm(PREDICTED_VALUE ~  PREDICTER_1 + PREDICTER_2 + PREDICTER_N  )
#summary(m1)
#anova(m1)

# after creating the model, we perturb as follows:
#install.packages("perturb") #install the package
library(perturb)
set.seed(1234)  # for same results each time you run the code
p1_new <- perturb(m1, pvars=c("PREDICTER_1","PREDICTER_N") , prange = c(1,1),niter=200)  # your can change the number of iterations to any value n. Total number of iteration would come to be n+1
p1_new  # check the values of p1
summary(p1_new)
```